# How do I create a lighttpd proxy rule to redirect on different ports based on URL param?

Tags: proxy, lighttpd

I currently have a `proxy.server` rule in `lighttpd.conf` that forwards all requests of `routemsg.pl` to port 1530:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "/routemsg.pl" {
    proxy.server = ( "" => ( ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 1528) ) )
}
```

How can I change the rule to allow the requester to pass a port param in the URL and that param be then used as the port to proxy the request to?

For example: A request of: `http://www.myip.com/routemsg.pl?p=1531` would go to `127.0.0.1` on port 1531.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `$HTTP["querystring"]` and capture the port with a conditional like this:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "/routemsg.pl" {
    $HTTP["querystring"] =~ "p=([0-9]+)" {
        proxy.server = ( "" => ( ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => "%1") ) )
    }
}
```

I sadly don't have a setup on which I can confirm that it works right now, I'm afraid. :(